# How to double-click a cell and copy value from a single-click of another cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I think this is pretty close but something is not quite right here.  I’m trying to double-click and cell in ColumnD and select a second Sheet, then click a cell in this second sheet, and the value is copied/pasted into the cell that I double clicked.  The thing is, I want to do this a few times, so if I double click the same cell 2 times, and jump to the second sheet 2 times, I want the value in the very first cell preserved.  So, If I have nothing in D3, then I double click it, I can select a cell in the second sheet.  Let’s say it is LQ1; this is copied/pasted into D3.  Then, I click D3 again, jump to the second sheet again, and select a cell in the second sheet.  Let’s say it is LQ2.  I want D3 to have LQ1 and LQ2 (and repeat over and over).

This is what I have so far.  I tried a couple ideas.  The thing is, when I click the cell in the second sheet, I don’t know how to get it to move back to the first sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        CellSelect = ActiveCell.Value
        CellAddress = ActiveCell.Address
        Sheets("Setup Questions").Select
        If Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B38")) Is Nothing Then
            Cancel = True
            Target.Copy
            Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty sure you'd need at least 2 event handlers for this - the `BeforeDoubleClick` in the "source" sheet and probably the `SelectionChange` in the "target" sheet. You'll also need to coordinate state between the two sheets. BTW, you should qualify `Range("B2:B38")` so you don't get a 1004 error.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best method is to achieve what you are trying to do, but I am almost 100% certain that it isn't by switching sheets in the middle of a `BeforeDoubleClick` event.  (Maybe use an `InputBox` to get the desired cell to be added to the `Target` cell?  I'll leave that up to someone else to decide.)

Comment: I believe I do need to switch back and forth between sheets.  How would I know what value to select from the second sheet and put in the first sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The InputBox idea got me thinking.  This seems to work . . .

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rng As Range

If Target.Column = 4 Then
CellSelect = ActiveCell.Value
CellAddress = ActiveCell.Address

Sheets("Setup Questions").Select
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Range(CellAddress).Value = CellSelect & Chr(10) & rng
Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Select

End If

Sheets("CP (POS) Tasklist").Select

End Sub
```